# Passing data between different view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

i want to get the username (`txtUsername`) from my loginView controller (`ViewController`) to `SecondViewController` in order to print the message "Welcome Username". I am using Segue (`login_success`) between the view controller. In my `SecondViewController` I have  `NSString` (`stringUsername`) to store the username from my `FirstViewController`. Here is my code in `SecondViewController`:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSString *segueIdentifier = [segue identifier];
    if ([segueIdentifier isEqualToString:@"login_success"]) {
        ViewController *homeController = (ViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        homeController.txtUsername.text = _stringUsername;
    }
}
```

When i set the break point it gives the output as "Printing description of self->_stringUsername:
(NSObject) NSObject = "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. You say:

   > I want to get the username (`txtUsername`) from my loginView controller(`ViewController`) to `SecondViewController`...

   In that case, your `prepareForSegue` should be in the source view controller, not the destination view controller. And the `segue.destinationViewController` would be `SecondViewController`, not `ViewController`.

   Frankly, I'm having trouble reconciling your intent, quoted above, with your code snippet (which is looks like you were trying to do a segue from `SecondViewController` to `ViewController`).
2. When you update the destination view controller, you should not try to set the `text` property of the `IBOutlet`. The `prepareForSegue` shouldn't try to use `IBOutlet` references at all, because when `prepareForSegue` has been called, the destination's view has not yet been instantiated and all of the `IBOutlet` references are likely `nil`.

   Instead, `prepareForSegue` in the source view controller should just set a `NSString` property in the destination controller. The responsibility for populating the `text` property of the `IBOutlet` on the basis of the `NSString` property falls upon `viewDidLoad` in the destination view controller.

Comment: thank you so much rob for taking out ur time to correct me as i am new here. I have more confusion but i will try to figure it out as thats the way of learning. thanks again.